# Display specified text for listbox items

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

I have a list that contains custom objects. These objects have different properties, and I have ~100 of them. I want to create a list of them in a listbox, but the listbox displays only

```
  MyNamespace.MyClass
  MyNamespace.MyClass
  MyNamespace.MyClass
  MyNamespace.MyClass
  ...
```

Is it possible to make the listbox display a certain value for each item? Lets say my objects have an ID string value. Can I display the ID for each item without discarding my objects' other properties?

I currently fill the listbox this way:

```
  lbox.Items.Clear();
  lbox.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `DisplayMember` to the property of your class that you'd like the user to see.

```
lbox.Items.Clear();
lbox.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());

lbox.DisplayMember = "ID";  // ID is a public property in MyClass
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets say you MyClass looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

There are two options available.

1. You can use DataBinding for that.

   **Set the `DisplayMember` to the propertie of your MyClass which you would like to display**

   ```
   lbox.DisplayMember = "Id";
   ```

   **Set the items using the `DataSource` propertie of your `ListBox`**

   ```
   lbox.DataSource = list.ToArray();
   ```
2. You can simple override the `ToString` method of your `MyClass` object and return the text you would like to display.

   **Override the `ToString` method of your MyClass**

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return Id.ToString();
       }
   }
   ```

   **Set the items the same way as you mentioned**

   ```
   lbox.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
   ```

#### More Information

- [MSDN: ListControl.DisplayMember Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN: Object.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Linq.

```
lbox.Items.AddRange(list.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray());
```

Where `ID` is a property with the value you want to show.

You can also override `ToString()` in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Without discarding the object you can attach the object to the tag after.

```
list.ToList().ForEach(item => lbox.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.ID){Tag = item});
```

then to retreive it :

```
var myitem = ((ListItem)lbox.SelectedItem).Tag as MyClass;
```